# Ghostscript compiling on HP-UX 11.31

Tags: ghostscript, hp-ux

Environment:

- HP-UX 11.31
- GCC 4.2.3
- Ghostscript 9.22

When trying to compile using ".\configure"
our Unix admin gets

```
Bad character | (octal 174), line 278Make: .  Stop.
```

When trying to make using "./configure CFLAGS="-Dinline=\"\"" --prefix=/usr/ghostscript --without-gnu-make"
our Unix admin gets:

```
     gcc   -O -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Werror=declaration-after-statement -fno-builtin -fno-common -Werror=return-type -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_DIRENT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_DIR_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIMES_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBDL=1 -DGX_COLOR_INDEX_TYPE="unsigned long long" -D__USE_UNIX98=1 -D"strnlen(a,b)=strlen(a)" -Dinline=""  -I./base -o ./obj/aux/genconf ./base/genconf.c  -lm -ldl
./base/genconf.c: In function 'read_token':
./base/genconf.c:891: warning: array subscript has type 'char'
..
./base/genarch.c: In function 'main':
./base/genarch.c:123: warning: unused variable 'sp'
        ./obj/aux/genarch ./obj/arch.h
..
```

---

When trying to make using "./configure CC=cc -Ae CFLAGS=-D_HPUX_SOURCE -O $(XCFLAGS)"
our Unix admin gets:

```
sh: XCFLAGS:  not found.
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-Ae'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

The same with -Aa.

Anyone else with HP-UX encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are going to complain about every warning during the Ghostscript build, you're going to spend a lot of time posting!

FWIW, we recommend using gcc, not the vendor's cc.

If you are intent on the using the HP cc, then you need to properly quote the options:
./configure CC="cc -Ae" CFLAGS="-D_HPUX_SOURCE -O $(XCFLAGS)"

Options are generally separated by spaces, so if you're options contain spaces, you have to add the quotes.